# Query and map one-way referenced children and sub-children from a parent with mongoose in Keystone.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

I got three models with one-to-many relationships. Simple tree. What I need is a simple, efficient way to query a structured relationship tree, preferably similar to mongoose's **.populate()** which I cant't use since I don't have id's on the parent model. I suppose keeping children ids on parent would be efficient, but Keystone doesn't provide this functionality by default and I am unable to write an update callback to control relational changes. I tried and wasted too much time, finding myself astray while maybe what I'm trying to achieve is much easier, but I just can't see it.

Here's the stripped code:

#### Category model

```
Category.add({
    name: { type: String}
});
Category.relationship({ path: 'sections', ref: 'Section', refPath: 'category' });
```

#### Section model, child of a category

```
Section.add({
    name: { type: String,  unique: true, required: true}
    category: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Category', many: false}
});
Section.relationship({  path: 'articles', ref: 'Article', refPath: 'section'});
```

#### Article model, child of the Section

```
Article.add({
    name: { type: String, required: true}
    section: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Section', many: false }
});
```

I want to get a structured view of a category with all children and their respective sub-children like this:

```
[ { _id: 57483c6bad451a1f293486a0,
    name: 'Test Category',
    sections: [
        { _id: 57483cbbad451a1f293486a1,
        name: 'Test Section',
        articles: [ 
            { _id: 57483c6bad451a1f293486a0,
             name: 'Test Category' } 
        ]
    ]
} ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that's how I did it. Not at all efficient but at least it's working. I didn't put anything in first-level parent since I need only one.

```
// Load current category
view.on('init', function (next) {

    var q = keystone.list('Category').model.findOne({
        key: locals.filters.category
    });

    q.exec(function (err, result) {

        if (err || !results.length) {
            return next(err);
        }

        locals.data.category = result;
        locals.section = locals.data.category.name.toLowerCase();           
        next(err);
    });

});


// Load sections and articles inside of them
view.on('init', function (next) {
    var q = keystone.list('Section').model.find().where('category').in([locals.data.category]).sort('sortOrder').exec(function(err, results) {

        if (err || !results.length) {
            return next(err);
        }

        async.each(results, function(section, next) {
            keystone.list('Article').model.find().where('section').in([section.id]).sort('sortOrder').exec(function(err, articles){
                var s = section;
                if (articles.length) {
                    s.articles = articles;
                    locals.data.sections.push(s);
                } else {
                    locals.data.sections.push(s);
                }
            });             

        }, function(err) {
            next(err);
        });

        next(err);
    });
});
```

But now I'm getting another issue. I'm using Jade 1.11.0 for templates and *sometimes* it doesnt't show the data in the view.
I will post another question for this issue.

Comment: All right, I figured out the error with next() firing too early. I fixed this piece of code in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528483/jade-template-doesnt-get-the-data-passed-from-express